# Struggling with a specific error.tuple indices must be integers, not float

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, tuples

I am struggling with a specific error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

I have seen some previous Questions but none of these really explains what this error means. I Understand it has something to do with creating arrays/matrices.
A brief description of this error would be much appreciated.

Here is a piece of my code

```
def Zed(K,M):
    if K == M:
        return Rk(K) + Rkp + 2*1j*W*10**(-7.0)*np.log(Dkkp/Ncheck(K))

    else: 
        return (Rk(K) + Rkp + 2*1j*W*10**(-7.0)*np.log(pythag(Conductors[K],Conductors[M],(Conductors[K+5]),((Conductors[M+5])-Dkkp))/Ncheck(K)))   

for K in range(5):
    for M in range(5):
        ZMatrix[[K],[M]] = Zed(Conductors[K],Conductors[M]) #this is where the error apears
```

and it throws the error I have mentioned above. I define ZMatrix as

```
ZMatrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: The error you quote is different from the error in your title. Which error are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to initialize your `ZMatrix` I would rather use:

```
ZMatrix =  [[0] * 5 for i in range(5)]
```

**Edit:** I originally used `*` to repeat generation in two dimension, that doesn't work as indicated in [python FAQ: How do I create a multidimensional list](//docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list), it can only be used for one dimension, and you need to use list comprehension (or for loops) to get the second dimension.

Secondly, when dereferencing list of lists, you need to keep the reference to the different lists apart, `ZMatrix[K][M]`, and not use a strange tuple reference, `ZMatrix[[K],[M]]`. So change your last line into:

```
ZMatrix[K][M] = Zed(Conductors[K], Conductors[M])
```

If this doesn't solve all of your problem, then you might need to look at the formula construction in your `Zed()` function.

Comment: Declaring your matrix as `ZMatrix = [ [0] * 5 ] * 5` is a bad idea because it will contain five references to the same inner list. https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, did just as in the faq and verified visually that it looked alright, but didn't test that it was actually different lists within the outer list.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ZMatrix[[K],[M]]
```

doesn't make sense. You are passing a tuple of two lists `([K],[M])` as an index to a list `ZMatrix`.

Perhaps you mean:

```
ZMatrix[K][M]
```

**Update:**

When you have a list and want to get an element out of it, you use an index inside square brackets.

```
mylist[index]
```

The index in this case should be an integer: 0 for the first element, 1 for the second, and so on.

A tuple is (usually) multiple items separated by a comma, such as `(1,2)`, or `(True, 'banana', 4)`.

When you write:

```
ZMatrix[[K],[M]]
```

you are passing your list `ZMatrix` a tuple . The tuple is `([K],[M])`.

Hence the error message "list indices must be integers, not tuple".

However, you can do this:

```
ZMatrix[K][M]
```

How this works is that `ZMatrix[K]` indicates element `K` of `ZMatrix`. That element itself is another list because of how `ZMatrix` was defined. Then we can refer to element `M` of the list `ZMatrix[K]` as `ZMatrix[K][M]`.

Comment: When I changed run it in the way you have recommended it throws the same error for the 5th line if the code. I am still rather unsure as to what exactly a tuple is? Thank you very much for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
([K][M]) is a tuple.
```

The correct syntax for accessing M<sup>th</sup> column element in the K<sup>th</sup> row is

```
 ZMatrix[K][M]
```

And make sure the name 'Conductors' is defined.